# How to prevent a Lion Cell Phone Battery from Discharging over 20-30 years?

Tags: batteries

I'm planning to make a time-capsule that is to be opened 20-30 years from today. In this capsule I want to put a cellphone from todays time. With it I want to include the cellphone battery, which is a Lithium Ion Battery. I'm not sure if the battery or even the electronics would survive that long. I was thinking of putting it into a vacuum sealed bag to prevent anything from going in or out.

Would a vacuum sealed bag prevent a battery from discharging?

Comment: You don't need to evacuate the cylinder. Use a PVC pipe for your cylinder. Put whatever you want in it, then add desiccant and oxygen absorber packets, and seal it up with end caps using PVC cement. Battery will not last 30 years. Sorry. But everything else probably will be fine. But like everyone says, you can still use it by powering it from an AC power source.

Comment: You may have considered this, but I would definitely uninstall the battery and provide instructions for how to inspect and reinstall it, and for how to use the phone anyway in case the battery fails inspection.  I would not trust a battery that old to not have leaked and ruined the phone.

Comment: The battery shelf (ie disconnected) life is best if left at 40% charge and kept cool, but even then it's unlikely to work after 30 years. Ten years, yes. The rest of the electronics should be fine but Flash memory may be corrupt or blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the phone NEED a Lion battery? Could you remove it, and just throw in a USB cable with instructions on how to connect 5v to it? In 50 years 5v will still be 5v.

I'd worry what a battery (ANY battery) will do when stored/buried for 20+ years, it could leak and ruin the contents of the capsule, self-combust, leak acid that will eat through environmental protection of the capsule, etc.

As others have said very long life batteries are available for a price. You could build one of those into a basic USB charger so future generations can power the thing up, and toss the Lion battery.

Oh and remember to write down the unlock code :p

Answer (score 8):

Self-discharge of a battery occurs *within the battery itself*, so there is no way to prevent it short of designing a better battery.

However it may be possible to (although perhaps not worth considering) use energy harvesting to bring the voltage of the (removed) battery back up to 4.0V whenever it drops to 3.2V.

Answer (score 3):

The only real certainty you can have is that if someone is around to dig it up in 30 years time, there's very likely to still be a sun around that creates solar and wind energy near the planet's surface.

So if an adaptor included in the package is not an option for you, you could consider solar cells. They are the cheapest and easiest to use solution that you can create and test now and reasonably expect/guarantee to still work the same in 30 years time. Although I see chances of a modern charger with 80 to 260VAC input allowance becoming unusable in that time as very, very, very slim.

Even batteries with a predicted lifespan of 30 years that lay in an acceptable budget have a statistical chance of failing over that time, be it very minuscule. (It may be minuscule enough compared to chances of your actual capsule failing and something damaging everything else inside anyway, that I cannot judge).

It all comes down to the fact that batteries with any mentionable capacity operate on chemistry and chemistry itself likes chaos more than order, so the ordered state of having electrons available on one side of a barrier will always decay over time under the pressure of the universe to want to create an equilibrium of chaos in the battery itself.

As Spehro mentions there are primary batteries that hold a charge long enough, even ones, if you have the money, that might hold it long enough with a very good guarantee of that, but for any capacity that can compensate enough for up to 30years of self-discharge you'll be spending so many dollars on just that battery that it's a better idea to put that money in a fixed high-interest 30year account and add a note with the bank details and an explanation of what kinds of voltages the phone needs on its contacts to operate and they can use the resulting capital in the future to spin up a production for just a single battery that fits.

Answer (score 2):

> or even the electronics would survive that long

I've heared that some early home computers were no longer useable after 25 years because of chemical processes within the silicon of the microchips.

Modern devices use Flash memory (for storing the operating system of the cell phone) which may also loose data over such a long time.

Another thing is the lead-free soldering tin which will also not survive a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

If cost was no object you might be able to use some lithium primary cells to supply the self-discharge current of the battery. If the battery held a charge for 3 months and you recharged it at that time, it would be 120 cycles, which is not too many. A slow trickle charge might work too (would have to be researched).

Primary cells that can be expected to hold a usable charge for 20, 25 30 and even 40 years are available, albeit expensive.

The chances of survival are better if the device is kept cool and dry. Plenty of stuff from 20 to 40 years ago still works, so the chances are not that low the phone and charger will work, but few batteries that old are still working very well.

Answer (score 0):

Place capsule in such a place that sun rays can reach to it and design such a capsule that is solar powered and connect its energy output to the ends of the battery. In this way you can "MAYBE" have the battery to last as long as 20-25 years. Next its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a method of generating power from within the cell itself? Perhaps you can calculate the amount of reactants you would need in a Daniell cell to remail stable over that period of time? or an aluminum air battery (may be a little dangerous)? At this point the project may become more of a study in battery cell technology than a lithium ion cell maximization problem. Depending on the work you need to do, you may be able to get away with an extremely weak cell to power a low power msp430 or the like. I seem to remember being told that it is possible to generate very small currents via electrodes of the correct composition in free soil...

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking specifically about Li-ion cells, then they will drain themselves through to internal self-discharge.  The rate of self-discharge for Li-ion cell is 1% to 2% per month <sup>1</sup>.

Primary Lithium cells have less self-discharge: 5% per year <sup>1</sup>.  Keep in mind that primary-lithium cells can supply only a small current on the order of units of mA.

One way to slow down self-discharge is to keep the cells at a lower temperature.  For this reason, common household batteries store longer in a fridge than at room temperature.

<sup>1</sup> Source: [article about self-discharge](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/elevating_self_discharge).  Inside there is a table with typical self-discharge figures for various battery chemistries.

*p.s.*  Interestingly, there is an exotic type of battery that can remain charged indefinitely.  [Molten Salt Battery.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten_salt_battery)  These types of battery is used in guided missiles that are stored in the arsenal for decades.